# Unity 3d. SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM and USE_EXACT_ALARM permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, android-permissions

Can't remove SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM and USE_EXACT_ALARM permissions

I have been disable checkboxes at mobile notifications settings [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsWB9.png)

But they are still present in AndroidManifest [AndroidManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH2ek.png)

I know where they are added. But they are added if I have these settings enabled and I have them disabled. [Adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7SYR.png)

I cannot debug this code, because it is executed during the build and the breakpoint is not placed there

I really hope for your help, I've been picking at this problem for a very long time

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your Android manifest file, Their permissions will be removed after build.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" tools:node="remove" />
```